# In the inventory, which mod does the second tab come from?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

[image]

I'm not sure where the second tab (the one with the image of a chestplate) is from. Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: A screenshot in which this tab is selected would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Tinker's Construct

The [Armor Tab](http://ftbwiki.org/Armor_Tab) is a feature of [Tinker's Construct](http://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/tinkers-construct) (FTB wiki link, but TC is in Yogscast Complete as well).

Sadly, there don't seem to be any official screenshots, but here's one I found on the Minecraft Forums via Google image search.

[image]